# RDS Server Not Interpreting Ctrl-S Command Correctly

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I've been investigating a strange issue with a customer's RDS server. We've narrowed the symptom down, but at this point I'm stumped.

Customer is running a database application on a Remote Desktop server (Server 2012 R2 Standard, running as a VM under Hyper-V). They have about 20 users logged into this server on an average day. They also have a handful of users running this application on local workstations, connected to the same server database. Issue is NOT reproducible on local workstations - only on RDS.

SYMPTOM:

When using this application, if a user performs a Ctrl+S action to save an entry in the software (invoicing/CRM software), *and the mouse is STATIC,* the line item is cleared and the entry is saved in a blank state.

If the user performs a Ctrl+S action *with the mouse MOVING*, the entry saves normally. Same with manually clicking File+Save, since the mouse is obviously moving.

We don't believe this to be an application issue, as we cannot reproduce this error on the other local workstations, which run the same software, same version. The vendor was not able to replicate the issue with a copy of the dataset. This error ONLY occurs on RDS - furthermore, we were able to reproduce this issue when logged into the RDS server using the domain admin user, thereby circumventing the Remote Desktop connection.

Could there be an OS-level fault here? Something with how the server is interpreting keyboard input?

Comment: *"This error ONLY occurs on RDS - furthermore, we were able to reproduce this issue when logged into the RDS server locally, eliminating the remote connection itself."*

Can you explain this ? If you are logged into the server locally (with a keyboard/mouse directly attached to it) you are not going through Remote Desktop layers, so it doesn't occurs only on RDS ? it occurs only on Windows Server.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, my error. When I say "locally," I mean that we logged into the machine via Splashtop using the domain admin - not a Remote Desktop connection with another AD user. I will update the question.